# The internal structure of PDF file

Tags: pdf

I am studying the structure of a PDF file.
How can I determine the info like paper size, margin and font sizes from a PDF file?
I know F13 is for Helvetica, but how about the other fonts? I cannot find them even from Adobe doc about PDF.

Answer (score 5):

> I am studying the structure of a PDF file.

Please do so using the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

> How can I determine the info like paper size,

Each page has its own size, it is defined in the **Page** dictionary or inherited:

> **MediaBox** rectangle *(Required; inheritable)* A rectangle (see 7.9.5, "Rectangles"),
>   expressed in default user space units, that shall define the
>   boundaries of the physical medium on which the page shall be
>   displayed or printed (see 14.11.2, "Page Boundaries").
>
> **CropBox** rectangle *(Optional; inheritable)* A rectangle, expressed in default user space
>   units, that shall define the visible region of default user space.
>   When the page is displayed or printed, its contents shall be clipped
>   (cropped) to this rectangle and then shall be imposed on the output
>   medium in some implementation-defined manner (see 14.11.2,
>   "Page Boundaries"). Default value: the value of **MediaBox.**
>
> *(Table 30 – Entries in a page object)*

[image]

> margin

There is no margin unless you mean a margin implied by some of the boxes above.

> and font sizes from a PDF file?

The size at which a font is used to draw some text is defined in the content stream by the **Tf** instruction and transformed by the current transformation matrix and text matrix.

> *font size* **Tf** Set the text font, *T<sub>f</sub>*, to *font* and the text font size, *T<sub>fs</sub>*, to *size*. *font* shall be
>   the name of a font resource in the **Font** subdictionary of the current
>   resource dictionary; *size* shall be a number representing a scale factor.
>   There is no initial value for either *font* or *size*; they shall be specified
>   explicitly by using **Tf** before any text is shown.
>
> *(Table 105 – Text state operators)*

Furthermore,

> I know F13 is for Helvetica,

There might be one PDF page for which that is the case but for the next one it might be **F2**, **Helv**, **ASDFjklgfklöjsflaksfd**, or whatever you want

Comment: for font sizes, how can i get the Tf instruction? The pdf file can only show 
garbled text. :(

Comment: It is all explained in the specification, [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). And if you don't want to implement, merely to analyze, there are numerous PDF structure browsers out there which decompress such streams for you to inspect, e.g. [RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/Products/itext-rups) or [PDFDebugger](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#pdfdebugger).

Comment: Can i find the font information(font size) in the pdf as a text file?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a tool dedicated to such a task. Please make that a stackoverflow question in its own right.